# Unable to Ping Voice Servers Provided by ISP

Tags: networking, router, voip, telephony

I am using a [Nokia ONT G-2425G-A](https://www.netronetworks.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/ONT-G-2425G-A-Four-Ethernet-One-Voice-and-dual-band-WiFi.pdf) router, with an Airtel home subscription in India.
The ISP provides Internet access as well as a VoIP connection. It works by attaching a physical telephone to the router itself.
In the router gateway, **two WAN connections** are visible. One for the Internet and the other (it seems) **exclusively for voice**.
The status page displays the Voice Soft Switch IP address.

I was wondering if it was possible to use a softphone application to connect to the voice switch to **make calls from a PC**.
But the problem was that the IP address is not accessible.

[image]

[image]

The first image shows both the WAN connections. (Left - Internet, Right - Voice only)
I logged into the router thru SSH and pinged the voice server three times from different sources - LAN, Internet-WAN-IP, Voice-WAN-IP. **Only the pings from Voice-WAN-IP worked.**
I think I need to use IP Routing settings to bind the Voice-WAN to LAN so a PC on my local network can access the Voice Switch.
But I have no idea how to do that.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The voice server IS responding to pings, but only when pinged from a different source IP. (shown in the second screenshot).
I also have the credentials for the voice server. But I haven't tested them because I am unable to connect with a device on LAN. Only the router is able to ping and connect but only thru the secondary WAN.

Comment: What does your current routing table look like? (Does the CLI let you `ip route get 10.x.x.x`?)

Comment: @u1686_grawity Not really. Only `ip route` works, and it returns an empty table. Maybe this is because I do not have full access to the router. I cannot modify anything thru its console.

Comment: Weird; most routers would show it at least through the web UI. (`netstat -rn`?)

Answer (score 0):

The SIP server might be set up not to respond to ping. Just because you can't ping it doesn't mean it is not accessible.

You would need a minimum of SIP address, username and authentication to be able to make calls from a softphone. Ideally you'd know the codec (but there are common ones you can try, and the protocol allows for some negotiation to occur).

Some SIP servers will not permit multiple simultaneous registrations to the same account, others are quite happy doing so. I use two VoIP providers only one allows multiple registrations. If you are in the first group then you will not be able to receive incoming calls to your softphone unless you first disable VoIP on your router.

It seems from updates to your Question that although you can reach the SIP server from your router you cannot get to it from your LAN. The router clearly has a route, so I suspect that the lack of connectivity from your LAN is simply because you're starting from a network that the SIP server cannot reach. Enable NAT on the router for the VoIP route (if you can).

Comment: @GreenFish answer updated - can you enable NAT for the VoIP route?

Comment: The NAT is indeed disabled for the voice WAN, but unfortunately the checkbox is locked, so I cannot enable it. Is there another way?

Comment: It might be worth asking around or searching to see if the SIP servers are actually publicly reachable. They might be on their own VLAN simply for QOS, and if you don't mind foregoing that you could potentially reach them via your normal Internet connection - or even via mobile if using it from a phone. But to answer the question directly, I know of no (other) ways to get around your situation

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be that you need a route, as the address 10.232.x is not on-link (i.e. not within any of your local subnets), so the router attempts to use the default route that it has from "Internet WAN".

Your `ping -I ..` doesn't specify a gateway (there's no option to do that anyway) and the result of such pings is as if the destination were on-link. Since that seems to work, manually add a route with empty gateway (or with 0.0.0.0 as gateway) for the destination you want. If that doesn't help – try a route with 172.23.29.234 as the gateway.

But that will not be enough, as it will only fix access from the router itself – the *router* is directly connected to that subnet and has an address in it; whereas your computer (which is on the LAN) *does not*. This is important because your ISP's SIP server needs to actually be able to send replies back to you – which works when you're pinging from the router, because the ISP has routes for 172.23.29.234 (which is your router's IP address)... but it will *not* have a route for your LAN subnet, not just because it is identical to 10000 other customers' LAN subnets so it's unreasonable to expect for it to have one.

**So in short, when your PC sends packets using its 192.168.1.7 address, the SIP server is not going to be able to reply back.**

For the 'Internet' connection, that issue is handled via NAT; the router masquerades all outbound packets from your LAN using its own IP address (which then becomes "your" WAN address). The same goes for the 'VoIP' connection – without special accommodation by the ISP, your router has to do NAT before forwarding anything into that VLAN, otherwise you'll never get any replies back from it. Since you say the 'NAT' checkbox is disabled, well, that's a problem.

You could probably get it to work by *bridging* the VoIP VLAN (660) to one of your LAN ports, then configuring the PC to recognize it as a tagged VLAN – and perhaps moving the router's IP address to the PC instead. I'm going to guess the router doesn't have that as an option either, though.